# How to change the color of Text in a card Flutter

Tags: flutter, colors, card

I'm starting with Flutter i'm trying to improve a Todo App and I need to change the color of text in my card child so it can be readable. Didn't find any solutions that i succeeded to put in my code. Here's the part where the cards with the text are implemented.

```
 Widget _buildTodoList() {
return new ListView.builder(
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index < _todoItems.length) {
      //return  _buildTodoItem(_todoItems[index], index);
      final item = _todoItems[index];
      return Dismissible(
          key: Key(item),
          onDismissed: (direction) {
            setState(() {
              _todoItems.removeAt(index);
            });
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(content: Text("$item  a été supprimé")));
          },
          background: Container(color: Colors.red),
          child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
              child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(title: Text("$item")),
                  color: Colors.blueGrey[900],
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ))));
    }
  },
);
```

}
I'd like to make the text of the item white. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the color of text by specifying color property for style in Text widget. Please see the code

```
Card(
                  child: ListTile(title: Text("$item", style:TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  color: Colors.blueGrey[900],
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                  ))));
```

Comment: thank you very much @bluenile, but I don't know where to put it

Comment: Please replace the code of your card with the code updated by me.

Comment: Please accept any answer that helped you and solved your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to add styling to the  the  Text widget like that:

```
Widget _buildTodoList() {
return new ListView.builder(
 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
   if (index < _todoItems.length) {
     //return  _buildTodoItem(_todoItems[index], index);
     final item = _todoItems[index];
     return Dismissible(
         key: Key(item),
         onDismissed: (direction) {
           setState(() {
             _todoItems.removeAt(index);
           });
           Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
               SnackBar(content: Text("$item  a été supprimé")));
         },
         background: Container(color: Colors.red),
         child: Container(
             margin: const EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
             child: Card(
                 child: ListTile(title: Text("$item", style:TextStyle(color: Colors.red))),
                 color: Colors.blueGrey[900],
                 shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                 ))));
   }
 },
);
```